# Removing newlines (\n) with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm parsing an HTML page with BS4:

```
import re
import codecs
import MySQLdb
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("sprt.htm"), from_encoding='utf-8')
sprt = [[0 for x in range(3)] for x in range(300)]
i = 0

for para in soup.find_all('p'):
    if para.strong is not None:
        sprt[i][0] = para.strong.get_text()
        sprt[i][1] = para.get_text()
        sprt[i][1] = re.sub(re.escape(sprt[i][0]), "", sprt[i][1], re.UNICODE)
        sprt[i][2] = sprt[i][1]
        sprt[i][2] = re.sub(r".+[\.\?][\s\S\n]", "", sprt[i][1], re.S)
        sprt[i][2] = re.sub(r".+Panel", "Panel", sprt[i][2], re.S)
        sprt[i][1] = re.sub(re.escape(sprt[i][2]), "", sprt[i][1])

i += 1
x = 0
```

The page I'm parsing is filled with paragraphs like those 3:

```
<p><strong>Name name. </strong>The Visual Politics of Play: On The Signifying Practices of Digital Games. Panel Proposal (2p)</p>
<p><strong>Name name and Name name. </strong>Pain, Art and Communication. Panel Proposal (2p)</p>
<p><strong>Name name, Name name and Name name. </strong>Waves of Technology: The Hidden Ideologies of Cognitive Neuroscience and the future production of the Iconic. Panel Proposal (2p)</p>
```

The parsing works properly until the last paragraph:

```
<p><strong>Name name, Name name and Name name. </strong>Waves of Technology: The Hidden Ideologies of Cognitive Neuroscience and the future production of the Iconic. Panel Proposal (2p)</p>
```

What I find in the last slot of the array is this:

```
[u'Name name, Name name\xa0and Name name.\xa0', u'Waves\n of Technology: The Hidden Ideologies of Cognitive Neuroscience and the \nfuture production of the Iconic.\xa0Panel Proposal (2p)', u'Waves\n of Technology: The Hidden Ideologies of Cognitive Neuroscience and the \nfuture production of the Iconic.\xa0Panel Proposal (2p)']
```

There are two newlines (`\n`) that appear in weird places (after `Waves` and before `future`). They always appear in the same position, not randomly.
I thought they were due to the length of the paragraph, but there are some longer paragraphs where no `\n` appears.

I tried to remove them with:

```
sprt[i][2] = re.sub("\n", "", sprt[i][1], re.U, re.S)
```

But it didn't work.

Are the newlines there because I made a mistake somewhere? Is there a way to remove them?

Comment: are they literal `\n` ?

Comment: no, when i copy past from the terminal to notepad++  if I search for "\n" i have nothing, it's a special '\' I guess.
If I do print sprt[][thelastline] i have somethnig like : 
   Waves [NEWLINE]      of Technology: The Hidden Ideologies of Cognitive Neuroscience and the [NEWLINE] future production of the Iconic.\xa0Panel Proposal (2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the newline actually appears in the source Html file. I tried to reproduce your error using your paragraphs and I didn't get any `\n` until I actually inserted a new line in the source file. This would also explain why it doesn't happen for other longer paragraphs: they simply don't have any actual newline in the html source file.

Having said that, if I add your `re.sub` line I do get the newline character removed. (I get that in `sprt[i][2]` though, not `sprt[i][1]` of course - is it possible you are looking in the wrong place there?)

Comment: I copy/pasted the 3 paragraphs from the html source file.
You are right. I was looking in the wrong place...
The `re.sub` line works fine and now the parsing is perfect.
Sorry it was my bad.  (I still don't understand where they come from tho)

Answer (score 0):

```
sprt[i][2] = re.sub(r"\n", "", sprt[i][1], re.U, re.S)

                   ^^
```

You can try with `raw` mode.

Comment: They are unaffected even with "raw" mode

Comment: because I was looking in the wrong place... It's working with `raw`